# why my global array has been updated after a function but my other global variable doesn't?

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

Imagine two situations below: We have an array which is a  global variable and it will be updated after a function. On the other hand as you can see in commented code my other global variable doesn't updated after a function?

I learnt about pass by reference and value, but i am wondering how come array has been passes by reference to the function but "a" variable has been passes as value?

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];

function adder(arrey, item) {
    arrey.push(item);
    return arrey.shift();
}


console.log(a);
console.log(adder(a,6));
console.log(a);
```

```js
var a =10

function adder (num) {
    num+=1;
    return num;
}

console.log(a);
adder(a);
console.log(a)
```

Comment: `num` is not `a`

Comment: 1. You cannot update primitives. JS is not pass-by-reference. 2. You probably shouldn't rely on global variables anyway.

Comment: `adder(a);` --> `a = adder(a);`

Comment: @Yousaf many thanks.  I learnt about pass by reference and value, but i am wondering how come array has been passes by reference to the function but "a" variable has been passes as value?

Comment: Everything in Javascript is _pass by value_. In the case of an array (or objects in general), value is a _reference_ to that object. So, if you pass an array to a function, you are passing a reference to that array. Any changes made to that array using its reference will modify the same array because in memory, there is only one array.